# zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file unable to store data into excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

hii folks I was scraping some data and storing to an excel file, earlier the code was working fine but I don't know why I am facing this error abruptly

this is code

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



# chrome_options=Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

##### Web scrapper for infinite scrolling page #####
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/hyderabad/gachibowli-restaurants/hyderabadi?rating_range=4.0-5.0&category=2")
time.sleep(10)  # Allow 2 seconds for the web page to open
scroll_pause_time = 1 # You can set your own pause time. My laptop is a bit slow so I use 1 sec
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")   # get the screen height of the web
i = 1
count=0

while True:
    # scroll one screen height each time
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height}*{i});".format(screen_height=screen_height, i=i))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
    # update scroll height each time after scrolled, as the scroll height can change after we scrolled the page
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    # Break the loop when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height
    if (screen_height) * i > scroll_height:
        break
page_sources= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
title=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='sc-jHZirH intUsQ']")
names=[]
addresses=[]
catagories=[]
for i in title:
    count += 1
    name =i.find_element_by_xpath('./div/h4').text
    address = i.find_element_by_xpath('./p[1]').text
    catags=i.find_element_by_xpath("./div[2]/p[@class='sc-1hez2tp-0 sc-fNHLbd hStwxV']").text
    names.append(name)
    addresses.append(address)
    catagories.append(catags)


df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': names, 'Addresses': addresses,'Categories': catagories })
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('hydrabad_Gachibowli.xlsx',mode='a')
df.to_excel(writer,'Hyde')
writer.save()

print(count)
driver.close()
```

and the error I am facing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/krishan/PycharmProjects/zomato/bakery.py", line 53, in <module>
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('hydrabad_Gachibowli.xlsx',mode='a')
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\web scrapping\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.book = load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\web scrapping\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 313, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\web scrapping\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\web scrapping\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\web scrapping\lib\zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\web scrapping\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

**block of code in which i am getting error** earliar it was working perfectly file

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': names, 'Addresses': addresses,'Categories': catagories })
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('hydrabad_Gachibowli.xlsx',mode='a')
df.to_excel(writer,'Hyde')
writer.save()
```

I looked for other solution but nothing makes me clear
please guys any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: "*.xlsx" files are zipped directories/files. In case you have a file (let's say a "*.csv" file, which is a flat textfile) and somebody has renamed this into "*.xlsx", just by modifying the extension, then it won't work.

So I would advise you to check if the "*.xlsx" file indeed has the correct format.

Comment: so you mean i need to write like this{    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('hydrabad_Gachibowli*.xlsx',mode='a') }  instead of writer = pd.ExcelWriter('hydrabad_Gachibowli.xlsx',mode='a')

Comment: your answer is confusing can you make it clear by using an example or applying thins to my code ,so that i could understand better